# History of PSL(2,Z)

Tags: mathematics, terminology, group-theory

I want to know the mathematician who named PSL(2,Z) as the modular group first. Also, I would be pleased if someone suggest to me some papers about the history of the modular group. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized that this notation comes from Bourbaki (say in the fifties' of the past century)

Comment: I would say Klein in Erlangen program.

Comment: Probably Klein and/or Fricke introduced the name.  Look in their book "Lectures on the Theory of Elliptic Modular Functions" (1890). Or see Fricke "Über die Theorie der automorphen Modulgruppen", Nachrichten Ges. Wiss. Göttingen, pages 91–101, 1896, which starts here: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1896?tify={%22pages%22:[103],%22view%22:%22info%22}